# export ID and column then later use these values to update the specified rows

Tags: mysql, database, bash

I have a script that runs mysqldump to export several tables from DB1. It runs the resulting SQL script on DB2. One of the tables contains an `inventory` column which needs to stay consistent on DB2 after the import of the script. I don't think there's any opportunity to preserve that particular value during the dump/import process, but I'd be open to such recommendations.

Instead, I'm trying to approach this with the following general process.

1. Dump the specified tables from DB1
2. Backup the inventories by ID on DB2
3. Import the dump from step 1 into DB2
4. Reset the inventories on DB2 from the backup in step 2.

I'm hoping to perform each of these tasks from bash.

```
ssh <server where DB1 lives>
mysqldump -u'' -p DB1 t1 t2 t3 > dump.sql
scp dump.sql <server where DB2 lives>
mysql ??? > inventory_backup.sql?
mysql -u'' -p DB2 < dump.sql
??? inventory_backup.sql?
```

I'm pretty open to alternative process recommendations, but schema changes are pretty much off the table. I'm rather disgusted by this task. I'd rather just separate the inventory out into it's own table which could be excluded from the dump/import, but that would require a pretty serious refactoring effort in the application layer that we just can't afford at the moment.

Comment: Does the table that contains inventory have the same number of rows after this process?  If not, can rows be added and/or deleted?

Comment: Rows can be added or deleted, but the IDs for the rows that still exist will be consistent. The inventory on any rows that are added need are trusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that copying the first database to the second wipes out the second database.  If that is not the case, then the process can be a bit simpler.

How about if you

1) copy the table that contains inventory:

```
create table tcopy select * from table_with_inventory;
```

2) mysqldump tcopy

3) copy the other database

4) restore tcopy

5) copy the values back

```
update table_with_inventory
inner join tcopy on table_with_inventory.id=tcopy.id
set table_with_inventory.inventory=tcopy.inventory
```

Comment: The process only wipes out the specific table so I can skip steps 2 and 4. This is the perfect solution. Thank you!